# How to get started with AVR Microcontrollers?

Tags: microcontroller, led, ac, avr, c

I have an `AVR` `ATMega32A` Microcontroller, a **Programmer** that supports my microcontroller, a **breadboard** and some electronic stuff like **AC power supply**, 5 **RGB LED**s and...
I also have **CodeVisionAVR** installed and I'm familiar with the `C` language.

I want to connect one of the **RGB LED**s to the microcontroller and write a program for it to turn on the LED, and then rotate the color of the LED (change hue smoothly).

I have no experience, (I repeat, NO EXPERIENCE) in electronics. So please help me to complete this project using those things.

Thanks very much.

Comment: You can find lots of nice AVR programming tutorials as well as basic electronics tutorials on YouTube. As far as I know, an AC power supply is not likely to be found with you. Also you should understand that this is not something that anyone here will say you "do this and this and this and yes you did it under 10 minutes". You should invest time on learning these stuff.

Comment: I would reccommend you first play around with a battery, LEDs, resistors and a multimeter first. Leave the AVR until you know how to light up the LED and why the measurements are what they are or else you will just end up frying it.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.

Comment: IF you are able to get your hardware to the running stage and write and compile code then what you have is excellent, and you need to be specific about what problems you have.   
eg what are the RGB LED part numbers and do you know how to power and drive them? 

**HOWEVER**, if you cannot do the above then I'd second Milan's answer of starting with an Arduino.   

Arduino + 5V supply + WIN PC USB connection + breadboard = going.

Comment: Arduinos can cost under $US5 (legitimate Arduino Nano clone from Ali Express) and allow you to start by focusing almost entirely on the actual task at hand.   
THEN you can go back to your superior system.

Answer (score 1):

I think since you have absolutely NO experience, you should learn with an arduino uno board. These boards are ready-to use for beginners and include an ATmega328p AVR microcontroller. You can find tons of tutorials on the internet for the Arduino device family and there's a lot to learn. Have fun!